# provide steps to deploy this contract from solidity by example

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-deployment, ethereumjs, signature

When i tried deploying this contract using 10 ethers, and then providing :

claimPayment()
-> amount - 9000000000000000000 i.e 9 ethers

-> nonce - 123

-> signature - 0x6162630000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 which is "abc"

I am getting this error -> *revert
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.*

edit : added payable in function, still issue persists.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/solidity-by-example.html#micropayment-channel

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
// This will report a warning due to deprecated selfdestruct
contract ReceiverPays {
    address owner = msg.sender;

    mapping(uint256 => bool) usedNonces;

    constructor() payable {}

    function claimPayment(uint256 amount, uint256 nonce, bytes memory signature) external {
        require(!usedNonces[nonce]);
        usedNonces[nonce] = true;

        // this recreates the message that was signed on the client
        bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, amount, nonce, this)));

        require(recoverSigner(message, signature) == owner);

        payable(msg.sender).transfer(amount);
    }

    /// destroy the contract and reclaim the leftover funds.
    function shutdown() external {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    /// signature methods.
    function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s)
    {
        require(sig.length == 65);

        assembly {
            // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix.
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            // second 32 bytes.
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes).
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        return (v, r, s);
    }

    function recoverSigner(bytes32 message, bytes memory sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(sig);

        return ecrecover(message, v, r, s);
    }

    /// builds a prefixed hash to mimic the behavior of eth_sign.
    function prefixed(bytes32 hash) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope you are trying to deploy this on remix . If you are then try to send zero amount then you will be able to deploy it on any network if u want. In my case i am deploying it on Sepolia Testnet [image]

[image]

After commenting your message verification code

`bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, amount, nonce, this))); require(recoverSigner(message, signature) == owner)`

My transaction went through , your signature is wrong here.

[image]

Comment: wanted to deploy it on remix vm

Comment: Yeah you can do it just dont enter any value for deployment and you can deploy it on remix vm

Comment: its getting deployed but inside the deployed contract, the claimPayment function is throwing an error.

Comment: Okay i just commented your code 
 bytes32 message = prefixed(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, amount, nonce, this)));

        require(recoverSigner(message, signature) == owner)

and my transaction went through looks like your signature is wrong

Comment: yeah signature part is getting error

Comment: So in order to create a sign you can use the following code . 

var hash = web3.utils.sha3("message to sign");
web3.eth.personal.sign(hash, web3.eth.defaultAccount, function () { console.log("Signed"); });

Comment: where should i run this js code

Comment: In vscode . Make sure to install web3 so that you dont get any dependencies error

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, the payable keyword is used to indicate that a function can receive Ether. If a function is not marked as payable, and you try to send Ether to it, the transaction will be reverted, and the Ether will not be sent. This is a safety feature to prevent unintentional transfers of Ether to contracts that are not designed to handle it.

Here is the simple fix:

```
function claimPayment(uint256 amount, uint256 nonce, bytes memory signature) external payable {
.......you code
```

Comment: i tried with payable, still the same issue persists.

Comment: Please read the question carefully because it is specified in the question that it was tried with payable and it did not work.